# Capture MouseDown event for .NET TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-mobile

Is there any way to capture the MouseDown even from the .NET 2.0 TextBox control?
I know the inherited Control class has the event, but it's not exposed in TextBox.
Is there a way to override the event handler?

I also tried the OpenNETCF TextBox2 control which does have the MouseDown event exposed, but no matter what I do, it doesn't fire the handler.

Any suggestions?

---

> What kind of crazy mobile device do
>   you have that has a mouse? :)

Yes, windows mobile does not have an actual mouse, but you are mistaken that Windows Mobile .NET do not support the Mouse events.  A click or move on the screen is still considered a "Mouse" event.  It was done this way so that code could port over from full Windows easily.  And this is not a Windows Mobile specific issue.  The TextBox control on Windows does not have native mouse events either.  I just happened to be using Windows Mobile in this case.

Edit:  And on a side note...as Windows Mobile is built of the WindowsCE core which is often used for embedded desktop systems and Slim Terminal Services clients or "WinTerms" it has support for a hardware mouse and has for a long time.  Most devices just don't have the ports to plug one in.

---

> According to the .Net Framework, the
>   MouseDown Event Handler on a TextBox
>   is supported. What happens when you
>   try to run the code?

Actually, that's only there because it inherits it from "Control", as does *every* other Form control.  It is, however, overridden (and changed to private I believe) in the TextBox class.  So it will not show up in IntelliSense in Visual Studio.

However, you actually can write the code:

```
textBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.textBox1_MouseDown);
```

and it will compile and run just fine, the only problem is that textBox1_MouseDown() will not be fired when you tap the TextBox control.  I assume this is because of the Event being overridden internally.  I don't even want to change what's happening on the event internally, I just want to add my own event handler to that event so I can fire some custom code as you could with any other event.

Comment: What kind of crazy mobile device do you have that has a mouse? :) Seriously, the reason there is no MouseDown event is because Windows Mobile doesn't have a mouse. What are you trying to do in the MouseDown event handler? Maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're right. Bummer. No MouseOver event.

One of the fallbacks that always works with .NET, though, is P/Invoke. Someone already took the time to do this for the .NET CF TextBox. I found this on CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TextBox_subclassing.aspx

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is way late, but hopefully it ends up being useful for someone who finds this. Also, I didn't entirely come up with it myself. I believe I originally found most of the info on the OpenNETCF boards, but what is typed below is extracted from one of my applications.

You can get a mousedown event by implementing the OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter interface and attaching it to your application's message filter.

```
static class Program {
    public static MouseUpDownFilter mudFilter = new MouseUpDownfilter();
    public static void Main() {
        Application2.AddMessageFilter(mudFilter);
        Application2.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

This is how you could implement the MouseUpDownFilter:

```
public class MouseUpDownFilter : IMessageFilter {
    List ControlList = new List();

    public void WatchControl(Control buttonToWatch) {
        ControlList.Add(buttonToWatch);
    }

    public event MouseEventHandler MouseUp;
    public event MouseEventHandler MouseDown;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message m) {
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        // If the message code isn't one of the ones we're interested in
        // then we can stop here
        if (m.Msg != WM_LBUTTONDOWN && m.Msg != WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            return false;
        }

        //  see if the control is a watched button
        foreach (Control c in ControlList) {
            if (m.HWnd == c.Handle) {
                int i = (int)m.LParam;
                int x = i & 0xFFFF;
                int y = (i >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
                MouseEventArgs args = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, x, y, 0);

                if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                    MouseDown(c, args);
                else
                    MouseUp(c, args);

                // returning true means we've processed this message
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now this MouseUpDownFilter will fire an MouseUp/MouseDown event when they occur on a watched  control, for example your textbox. To use this filter you add some watched controls and assign to the events it might fire in your form's load event:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Program.mudFilter.WatchControl(this.textBox1);
    Program.mudFilter.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(mudFilter_MouseDown);
    Program.mudFilter.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(mudFilter_MouseUp);
}

void mudFilter_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (sender == textBox1) {
        // do what you want to do in the textBox1 mouse down event :)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the .Net Framework, the [MouseDown Event Handler on a TextBox](http://www.csharpfriends.com/quickstart/aspplus/samples/classbrowser/cs/classbrowser.aspx?assembly=System.Windows.Forms,%20Version=1.0.5000.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089&namespace=System.Windows.Forms&class=TextBox) is supported. What happens when you try to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Fair enough. You probably know more than I do about Windows Mobile. :) I just started programming for it. But in regular WinForms, you can override the OnXxx event handler methods all you want. A quick look in Reflector with the CF shows that Control, TextBoxBase and TextBox don't prevent you from overriding the OnMouseDown event handler.

Have you tried this?:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something specific here
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there an 'OnEnter' event that you could capture instead?

it'd presumably also capture when you tab into the textbox as well as enter the text box by tapping/clicking on it, but if that isn't a problem, then this may be a more straightforward work-around